# Remove duplicated string stored in variable

Tags: unix, scripting, ksh, mks

I have a variable `$var` with this content:

```
var=word1,word2,word3,word1,word3
```

and I need to delete duplicate words and the results is required stored in the same variable `$var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    var="word1,word2,word3,word1,word3"
    list=$(echo $var | tr "," "\n")
    var=($(printf "%s\n" "${list[@]}" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rnk1 | awk '{ print $2 }'))
 echo  "${var[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If open to `perl` then:

```
$ var="word1,word2,word3,word1,word3"
$ var=$(perl -F, -lane'{$h{$_}++ or push @a, $_ for @F; print join ",", @a}' <<< "$var")
$ echo "$var"
word1,word2,word3
```